# Confront Distribution of 2 samples

Tags: r, distributions, sample

I found this problem during an interview, and I have little or no clue on how to proceed.

Say you have two samples, of *different* length:

```
a <- c(1.79, 1.59, 1.93, 1.64, 1.03, 1.37, 1.13, 1.88, 1.92, 1.28)
b <- c(2.26, 1.95, 2.11, 2.44, 1.75, 2.37, 1.79, 2.21)
```

given just this information, what can you say about the *underlying* *distribution* of the samples?

Can you say that they come from the *same* distribution?If so, how?

I'd like to understand different approaches to this kind of question (*Theory* and/or  *Logical*).

Some code is welcome too.

Update:

As an example I tried the `ks.test`, but this gives me inconsistent results:

```
set.seed(123)

a <- sample(seq(1.00,2.00, by=0.01), 10)
b <- sample(seq(1.50,2.50, by=0.01), 8)

ks.test(a,b)$p.value
#0.03729604
```

Comment: It is possible to compare two distributions to check if they come from the same underlying distribution, ex. Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: You could also try using a graphical aid, such as the QQ plot. In R, you can use `qqplot(a, b); abline(0, 1)` to see how the samples compare. You can tell a lot by looking at QQ plots - including whether a distribution is a linear transform of another, if it's more or less skewed or peaked w.r.t. the other distribution, etc.

Comment: but is it reliable on such small samples?

Comment: I shouldn't have a clue how to proceed either, without *any* information on what the data represent or how they're sampled; or on what kind of difference between the two populations from which the samples are drawn is plausible, or of interest. You could get somewhere by assuming measurements on an interval scale, independently & identically distributed, & stipulating, say, a location-shift alternative - that is by assuming a paucity of imagination & lack of statistical experience on the part of your interviewers.

Comment: Exactly, I was wondering if a more logical answer would even exist. FYI I seem to recall that there was an option that the question lacked information.

Comment: Assuming that they are some kind of measurement, and i.i.d., would make a difference? In that scenario, Will I have only the option to rely on a test, like KS?

Comment: Graphical methods are especially useful in exploratory analysis, for suggesting ways in which the populations from which the samples are drawn may differ. To use formal tests you need to define a test statistic that's sensitive to the kind of difference you're most interested in detecting (the KS statistic estimates the gap between the distribution functions at its widest, so it's a good general-purpose one if you're not focused on location shift, change of scale, or whatever specifically). The acme of inference is to have a statistical model in which one or more parameters ...

Comment: ... describe the difference & to obtain point & interval estimates for those - answering the question of *how much* the populations differ (that they do differ is often something you can take for granted). Anyway (I was rather going off on one), the interviewers doubtless meant to say that these are simple random samples, with measurements on at least an interval scale, & they're expecting you to suggest some distribution-free procedures (compare & contrast), probably with bonus points for discussing graphical methods.

Comment: By the way, I don't understand what you mean when you say the results of the KS test are inconsistent.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but with `0.03729604` we reject $H_0$, and I used `sample`, shouldn't it accept the null that they come from the same distribution?

Comment: Plus I said that it's inconsistent because if I run it again It may accept $H_0$ (I tried), that's why I was looking for a more "logical" answer.

Comment: (1) Your samples do come from different distributions, so you'd hope to reject the null hypothesis. (2) If you had a procedure that gave the same answer regardless of how the samples turn out, then why would you bother sampling? The idea of a statistical test is to control the chance of wrongly rejecting the null hypothesis to no more than, say, 5%.